# HTTP GET failing

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, http

I have an activity script running a SSJS HTTP GET request. 
I need to get the output of this request to feed a data extension.

I am using this code:

```
var de= DataExtension.Init("dataextension_ek");
var headerName =["Authorization","Authorization2"];
var headerValues = [value, SHA1(value2)];
var url ="url.to.request.com";

try{
   HTTP.Get(url, headerName, headerValues);
   de.Rows.Add({field1:"sucess");
}catch(e){
   de.Rows.Add({field1:e);
}

function SHA1(msg){...}
```

to perform the request.
If i perform the same request on my local console, i get the expected results. However on activity script i keep getting an 400 error status.

Has anyone have similar issues?

Thanks,

Comment: headerName var is capitalized in Get, but not in above where you set value (var headername =).

Comment: Many thanks Gortonington. The code i provided is a partial copy of the one i am using, still i have updated the wrong written var in this example. On my script activity the code is successfully validated.